# What is the best way to use maya and a custom python location at the same time? (Maya & PYTHONHOME issue)

Tags: python, maya

If I startup maya while using the PYTHONHOME windows env variable (not maya.env) I get a "Invalid Python Environment" error while running the usersetup.py file.

How does one use maya while also using the PYTHONHOME env variable to point towards a non-standard install of python?

Comment: Are you trying to run scripts from a different location than the standard folder? Then take a look at https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya/files/Environment-Variables-File-path-variables-htm.html and the PYTHONPATH. Otherwise you can append to a custom path using `sys.path.append("/path/to/folder/with/python-scripts/")`